# Generic MemoryCache class

Tags: c#, cache

I want to have a caching class to cache different types.  I want each type to be cached in a different `MemoryCache` but in a generic way.

Am I doing it right?

```
internal static class RecordsCache
{
    private static Dictionary<string, ObjectCache> cacheStore;
    static private CacheItemPolicy policy = null;

    static RecordsCache()
    {
        cacheStore = new Dictionary<string, ObjectCache>();

        ObjectCache activitiesCache = new MemoryCache(typeof(Activity).ToString());
        ObjectCache lettersCache = new MemoryCache(typeof(Letter).ToString());
        ObjectCache contactssCache = new MemoryCache(typeof(Contact).ToString());

        cacheStore.Add(typeof(Activity).ToString(), activitiesCache);
        cacheStore.Add(typeof(Letter).ToString(), lettersCache );
        cacheStore.Add(typeof(Contact).ToString(), contactssCache );

        policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
        policy.Priority = CacheItemPriority.Default;
        policy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddHours(12);
    }

    public static void Set<T>(string userID, int year, List<T> records)
    {
        var cache = cacheStore[typeof(T).ToString()];
        string key = userID + "-" + year.ToString();
        cache.Set(key, records, policy);
    }

    public static bool TryGet<T>(string userID, int year, out List<T> records)
    {
        var cache = cacheStore[typeof(T).ToString()];
        string key = userID + "-" + year.ToString();

        records = cache[key] as List<T>;
        return records != null;
    }

    public static void Remove<T>(string userID, int year)
    {
        var cache = cacheStore[typeof(T).ToString()];
        string key = userID + "-" + year.ToString();
        cache.Remove(key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Instead of having a cache

   ```
   private static Dictionary<string, ObjectCache> cacheStore;
   ```

   you could have one keyed of the types:

   ```
   private static Dictionary<Type, ObjectCache> cacheStore;
   ```

   This means you don't need to call `typeof(T).ToString()` everywhere.
2. You duplicate the code of building the key in all 3 methods - it should be extracted into a private `BuildKey(string userId, int year)` method. This means if you need to change how the key is built you only need to touch one method rather than all of them.
3. I would provide a `Register` method which accepts a type for which to create a new cache rather than hard-coding it in.
4. The cache policy is also not configurable - which means you are stuck with it unless you want to change the code.
5. You really really should think hard about whether a static cache is the right way to go. It will give you trouble in unit testing and it will also make it impossible for multiple classes to have different cache with different policies for example.

Comment: Thanks, very valuable tips. I am no programmer in real life, it is just a hobby. I never had a programming courses or so. So your tips are like gold to me :)

Comment: One more issue with keeping the class static is that it's not thread-safe. And static classes that are not thread-safe are almost unusable in multi-threaded programs (and should be very clearly documented as such).

Comment: @svick but the CacheMemory itself is threadsafe, wouldn't that make it thread safe?

Comment: @MeNoTalk I guess you're right. `Dictionary` isn't thread-safe, but you only read from it (unless you follow Chris's advice about `Register()`), so that should be okay.

Answer (score 2):

From my point of view, everything is well coded.

Just some personal preference here:

1. I would provide 1 more `Set<T>` method which accepts a func as input instead of `List<T>`:

   ```
   public static void Set(string userId, int year, Func<List<T>> retrieveData) { }
   ```
2. I would like to have 1 more method to combine `Get` and `Set` together which looks like:

   ```
   public List<T> TryGetAndSet(string userId, int year, Func<List<T>> retrieveData)
   {
       //if cache item exist return cacheItem 
       //if cache item does not exist, retrieve data by executing retrieveData
       //  If any result retrieved, set to cache and return as result
   }
   ```
3. 1 more item to check whether certain cache item exists